# Custom adapter creation in SAP PI 7.1

Tags: sap-pi, sap-xi

We have a requirement to create Custom Adapter in PI. Can you guys help me out sharing your ideas, experiences regarding this?

I am using SAP PI 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

the task for writing Receiver is relatively simple (as far as I know). For writing Sender, there is more troubles. Look at sourceforge.net, there was an open-source adapter with some docs.

If you want, I can help you in writing but I have no out-of-the-box experience.

Comment: We can start with receiver side adapter... What are the basic things do I need to know for this?